# How to create a node reference when a link or button is clicked?

Tags: nodes

I set up a [nodereference](http://drupal.org/project/references) from a user to a node. The user can reference multiple nodes but I don't want him to select those in the user profile, which would be the default behavior.

I want to show an "add" button or link on the node page and when the user clicks it I want to create the node reference.

The table schema is pretty straight forward but I would think there is a function available?

Comment: does this NEED to be a nodereference?  I am thinking with the limited information here a flag (http://drupal.org/project/flag) would accomplish the same thing, and all that functionality is already built for you.

Comment: I could use entity references in a pinch. But flag won't do, I'm building a basic OG feature, just without OG (long story) ;-)

Comment: guess you are stuck with a node_load(), set the field, node_save() kinda menu callback or form function (and hiding the fields from edit on the profile)

Comment: yeah, or a user_load in this case. I think I'll go with flags after all. Thanks!!!